# Combine Result of three tables without Repetition

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables Users, Qualification & Work History.

USER_ID is primary key in Users table and serve as FK in other two tables.

Users table has one to many relationship with other two tables i.e. A user can have multiple degrees as well as many past jobs.

```
user_id  degree  year
-------  ------  ----
      1  BS      1950
      1  MS      1952
      1  Ph.D    1960
      2  BS      1990
```

and

```
user_id   Designation        From Year  To Year
-------  ------------------  ---------  -------   
      1   SSE                1955       1958
      1   System Architect   1960       1965
      2   Lab Engineer       1996       1997
      2   Lab Supervisor     1998       1999
```

I have tried using INNER JOIN and LEFT JOINS but they do not create the desired output

```
SELECT users_qualification 
 INNER
  JOIN users_work 
    ON users_qualification.user_id = users_work.users_id
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM users where job_id = 400)
```

`[INNER] JOIN` works as expected creating a relationship of every degree with each work experience. However what I am looking for is as follows:

```
user_id  Degree  year  Designation        From Year  To Year
-------  ------  ----  -----------------  ---------  -------
     1   BS      1950  SSE                1955       1958
     1   MS      1952  System Architect   1960       1965
     1   Ph.D    1960 
     2   BS      1990  Lab Engineer       1996       1997
     2   ---     ---   Lab Supervisor     1998       1999
```

Is it possible to create such concatenation in (T-)SQL or i have to resort to traditional languages ?

Comment: What is the meaning of "**(T-)SQL**" in the question? Is that an abbreviated reference to "Transact-SQL" ala Microsoft SQL Server? We note the question is tagged as "MySQL", so are we to assume that what was meant was **SQL**. If this question is about MySQL, the usage of "**(T-)SQL**" in the question is confusing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Actually preferrable way is plain SQL however if anything is possible in T-SQL i can port the database to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create this resultset using SQL constructs, but it's rather ugly.

We would need to define a finite upper limit on the number of rows to be returned for each `user`. And we could use inline views to assign sequential "row number" for rows returned from each table.

That is, we could write queries to return results like this, for qualification

```
_rn  user_id  degree  year
---  -------  ------  ----
 1         1  BS      1950
 2         1  MS      1952
 3         1  Ph.D    1960
 1         2  BS      1990
^^^
```

and this for job_history

```
_rn  user_id   Designation        From Year  To Year
---  -------  ------------------  ---------  -------   
 1         1   SSE                1955       1958
 2         1   System Architect   1960       1965
 1         2   Lab Engineer       1996       1997
 2         2   Lab Supervisor     1998       1999
^^^
```

We could write an outer query against the `user` table creates repeated copies of the user, like this:

```
 user_id  _rn   
 -------  ---
       1   1
       1   2
       1   3
       1   4
       1   5
       1   6
       1   7
       2   1
       2   2
          ^^^
```

Then we could do outer joins to the other two sets. Query would be of form something like this:

```
 SELECT u.user_id
      , q.degree
      , q.year
      , j.designation 
      , j.from_year
      , j.to_year
   FROM user u 

  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS _rn UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 5 ... ) r 

   LEFT 
   JOIN ( /* qualifications_rn_query */
        ) q
     ON q.user_id = u.user_id
    AND q._rn     = r._rn 

   LEFT 
   JOIN ( /* job_history_rn_query */
        ) j
     ON j.user_id = u.user_id
    AND j._rn     = r._rn

  WHERE ( q._rn IS NOT NULL OR j._rn IS NOT NULL )
  ORDER
     BY u.user_id 
      , r._rn
```

It's possible. But like I said earlier. It would be ugly.